# Why is the weather radar mounted on the left wing of the TBM?

Tags: general-aviation

Weather radar is mounted starboard on the Pilatus PC12 or in the Piper Meridian/M600/M500.

It adds drag to the right wing, thus a right yawing moment, and helps to counteract the slipstream effect and P-factor that tends to yaw the aircraft to the left.

So why is the wx-radar mounted port on the TBM ? (the propeller rotates in the same direction as the PC12, so it seems like the wx-radar only adds more yaw to the left)

Comment: Because it's French?

Comment: @JuanJimenez: "*Because it's French?*", hum those guys have pioneered aviation, to the point [aviation is a French word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aviation).

Comment: @mins Aviation was invented before the French even knew they existed as a people, but I can see the French have yet to invent comedy.

Comment: I sent a query to TBM to try to find out.

Comment: I sent a query to the sales department at TBM as promised, but they never answered.

Comment: Another context for radar pod ( probably wouldn't be described as "weather radar" ) and TBM : https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/hyperscale/am-1-48-avenger-radar-pod-question-which-is-best-d-t204685.html

Comment: Perhaps to have less wiring distance from the unit to the display in the cockpit? Any ideas on the cockpit layout for the 2 craft?

Answer (score 1):

After some detective work I have concluded:

In the TBM planes, the center portion of the right wing leading edge is occupied by the stall warning vane (or an optional AOA sensor in newer models). The two pitot tubes are located under each wing and landing lights are positioned at wingtips. This would leave the current location for the optional weather radar pretty much the only option available.

[image: locations of stall vane and pitot tubes on TBM 850, as for these, all TBM models are identical]

[TBM 700C pilot information manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.tbm.aero/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/PIM_700C_E0R8-WEB.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiVjpib-cDkAhWrtYsKHbNkAUoQFjALegQIBhAH&usg=AOvVaw0F05xtAVO_ir4qZ1MVmcV7), stall warning vane description on page 7.15.1

[Source for picture](https://www.bjtonline.com/aircraft/daher-socata-tbm-850)